# Objective-C: What does [ClassName self]; do?

Tags: objective-c, class, class-method, httpserver

I'm looking through the source code for the [CocoaHTTPServer project](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer/blob/master/Core/HTTPServer.m), more specifically the `HTTPServer.m` file and I just don't understand this line:

```
connectionClass = [HTTPConnection self];
```

What does this do (is it documented anywhere)? How does it even compile? Should it not be

```
connectionClass = [HTTPConnection class];
```

Comment: Actually it's pretty clear that method `self` called on a class returns the class. The tricky part is why method `class` called on a class returns the class and not its metaclass :)

Comment: I really wish people would use `[ClassName self]` instead of `[ClassName class]`. That would reduce the confusion between `+class` and `-class`. But alas, it's pretty ingrained at this point

Comment: @Sulthan: and to add to the confusion, in Smalltalk, `ClassName class` *does* return the metaclass ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, `- (id)self` is a method defined on `NSObject`. It returns the receiver. For a `Class` it should obviously do the same as a call to the `-(Class)class`.

> Class objects are thus full-fledged objects that can be dynamically typed, receive messages, and inherit methods from other classes. They’re special only in that they’re created by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've found an interesting post http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html describing classes/meta-classes. Relevant bit: *Every Class in Objective-C is an object itself. This means that the Class structure must start with an isa pointer so that it is binary compatible with the objc_object*.

Comment: That's for the question. I learned a lot when I was trying to answer it.

Comment: that should be `+(Class)class`, not `-(Class)class`, which does something completely different

Answer (score 3):

`[Classname self]` is equal to `[Classname class]` and returns a reference to the `class` object.

A little sample code illustrates this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
NSAutoreleasePool *p = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSLog(@"Output 1: %@ address:%x",[NSString self], [NSString self]);
NSLog(@"Output 2: %@ address:%x",[NSString class], [NSString class]);

[p release];
```

}

Output:

```
2012-02-22 15:36:13.427 Untitled[1218:707] Output 1: NSString address:7b306a08
2012-02-22 15:36:13.428 Untitled[1218:707] Output 2: NSString address:7b306a08
```

Comment: I guess I'm confused because the self method declared in the NSObject protocol is an instance method not a class method - (id)self. So is it because the Class is itself an objective c object which can receive a self message?

Comment: Of course it is. When you are declaring a class method, you are actually adding an instance method to the class. Note that you can override a class method in a subclass. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html

Answer (score 2):

`[className self];` is same as `[className class];`
Returns the class object.
For example:

```
id object = [getSystemEventsAppDelegate self];
id object1 = [getSystemEventsAppDelegate class];
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

In a very basic nutshell `self` is a reference to the current object, you pass that as a variable to (in this case) HTTPConnection, then assign the result of that method to the variable.

So if you look at HTTPConnection you'll be able to see how it uses that object reference and what it's going to return.

Comment: What are you talking about? `HTTPConnection` isn't a method, and even if it was, that's not the right syntax for passing an argument in a message.