# Why isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse self] instead of isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]?

Tags: objective-c, class, self

According to Apple...
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/URLCache/Listings/Classes_URLCacheConnection_m.html

...we should do:
`if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse self]])`

Is it the same as doing `if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]])`?

Comment: There is no difference: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396746/objective-c-what-does-classname-self-do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, **Martin R**'s comment is right, it's the same.
For any class, I can do either `[ClassName self]` or `[ClassName class]` for the same result.
And I can override both of them:

```
+ (Class)class
{
    return [super class];
}
+ (id)self
{
    return [super self];
}
```

In fact, all NSObject instance methods (-) become class methods (+) for a Class.

Pro about manipulating 'self':

- we are directly manipulating a Class, so no need to ask for the class of a Class

Con about manipulating 'self':

- it is low-typed as 'id'.

Answer (score 0):

Both `-[NSObject self]` and `+[NSObject class]` do the same thing: return the object it was called on. No class implements a `+self` class method, so when you call `self` on a class object, it calls the `-[NSObject self]` method, since metaclasses inherit ultimately from `NSObject` (meaning that all instance methods of `NSObject` are available to class objects, unless overridden by a class method of the same name).

I wish that the Cocoa library writers would have never had `+class`, and we would just always use `[ClassName self]` instead of `[ClassName class]`, because now people always confuse `+[NSObject class]` with `-[NSObject class]` (which do very different things -- `+[NSObject class]` returns the (class) object it was called on, whereas `-[NSObject class]` returns the class of the object it was called on).

Comment: as written in my answer, all NSObject instance methods (-) become class methods (+) for a Class. This means that technically it wouldn't have been possible to avoid a `+class` method. And for the same reason, we have a +hash, +superclass, +self, +zone, +isProxy, +retain, +release, +autorelease, +retainCount, +description, +init, +dealloc, +finalize, +copy, +mutableCopy, +allowsWeakReference, +retainWeakReference, +classForCoder, +autoContentAccessingProxy, ...

Comment: @Cœur: `+` and `-` denote where a method is implemented in the code. At runtime, there are just messages and objects; and no distinction between instance methods and class methods -- they are all methods of objects. So I am talking about the `-[NSObject self]` method (which of course can be used by all objects that are instances of `NSObject`, including class objects of classes that descend from `NSObject`) and the `+[NSObject class]` method.